# Pod install error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I get this error when trying to install pods with Cocoapods through the `pod install` command. I just updated to Cocoapods 0.33.1, I don't know if that's what causing this.
I looked on Cocoapods Github repo, but there doesn't seem to be a similar issue.

````
### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 0.33.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
    RubyGems : 2.0.14
        Host : Mac OS X 10.9.3 (13D65)
       Xcode : 5.1.1 (5B1008)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ a9178ca54fa395859f71056e7015fd125fa93495
```

### Podfile

```ruby
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'OpenWeatherMapAPI', '~> 0.0.5'
```

### Error

```
RuntimeError - [!] Xcodeproj doesn't know about the following attributes {"name"=>"JSON"} for the 'PBXReferenceProxy' isa.
Please file an issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/issues/new
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:300:in `configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:230:in `new_from_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:328:in `object_with_uuid'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:279:in `block (2 levels) in configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:278:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:278:in `block in configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:275:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:275:in `configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:230:in `new_from_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:328:in `object_with_uuid'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:291:in `block (3 levels) in configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:290:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:290:in `block (2 levels) in configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:288:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:288:in `block in configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:285:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:285:in `configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:230:in `new_from_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:175:in `initialize_from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:93:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:517:in `block in compute_target_platforms'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:514:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:514:in `compute_target_platforms'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:55:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:176:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:98:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:52:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:97:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:89:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:40:in `run_install_with_update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:70:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.6.1/lib/claide/command.rb:281:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:48:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.33.1/bin/pod:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```
````

What should I do?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you don't get an answer here please open an issue on the [main repo](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods)

Comment: I did already! https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2191